# .Net Identity User Manager Class GenerateNewTwoFactorRecoveryCodesAsync not saving new codes in DB

Tags: c#, .net-core, identity, two-factor-authentication

I am using the Scafolded Identity templates and have the made this changes to the GenerateRecoveryCodes.cshtml.cs file:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{user.Id}'.");
        }            
        
        if (!user.TwoFactorEnabled)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Cannot generate recovery codes for user as they do not have 2FA enabled.");
        }

        var recoveryCodes = await _userManager.GenerateNewTwoFactorRecoveryCodesAsync(user, 10);
        RecoveryCodes = recoveryCodes.ToArray();

        _logger.LogInformation("User with ID '{UserId}' has generated new 2FA recovery codes.", user.Id);
        
        return RedirectToPage("./ShowRecoveryCodes");
    }
```

when this page is called, it calls the User Manager class "GenerateNewTwoFactorRecoveryCodesAsync" method and this method is supposed to replace the existing codes with the new ones. But instead, generates the new codes but don't replace the existing ones.

User Manager class code:

```
    public virtual async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GenerateNewTwoFactorRecoveryCodesAsync(TUser user, int number)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        var store = GetRecoveryCodeStore();
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
        }

        var newCodes = new List<string>(number);
        for (var i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            newCodes.Add(CreateTwoFactorRecoveryCode());
        }

        await store.ReplaceCodesAsync(user, newCodes.Distinct(), CancellationToken);
        var update = await UpdateAsync(user);
        if (update.Succeeded)
        {
            return newCodes;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Note that this class is locked and the code in it can't be changed**

If I have no codes in the database then the generated codes are saved without a problem.
Can anyone help me understand the issue why the codes are not replaced if already exist some codes in the DB?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing `UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)`
from my services.AddDbContext options

Comment: I made those changes but it still did not work